# Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Providers meaning for LoweredApplicationName

Tags: sql, membership-provider

Im using Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Provider to setup USERS, ROLES and MEMBERSHIP for my website.
I can see new table in my DataBase.

I would like to know what is used for:

table:

```
aspnet_Applications
```

fields:

```
LoweredApplicationName
```

and table:

```
aspnet_Users
```

fields

```
LoweredUserName
MobileAlias
```

Thanks guys for your great support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post but it ranks highly on Google.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx